# Intellij IDEA. Свой автокомплит

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Создаю в проекте файлы:

```
ru.properties
en.properties
```

каждая строка - ключ=значение

Создаю класс:

```
class Localization {}
```

В классе один метод

```
public String get(String key) {...}
```

Как подсказать IDE IDEA, что ключи надо искать в файлах локализации? Возможно ли это? Т.е. нажаш клавишы автокомплита, идея должна предложить мне варианты.
Спасибо.